# Filter out an array from another array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

So I have 2 arrays of objects, it looks like this

```
    this.balanceCodes = [
        { ID: 1, StringValue: "dummy" },
        { ID: 2, StringValue: "data" }
    ];
    this.allCodes = [
        { ID: 1, StringValue: "dummy", Color: "red", Order: "low" },
        { ID: 2, StringValue: "data", Color: "green", Order: "medium" },
        { ID: 3, StringValue: "extra", Color: "black", Order: "low" },
        { ID: 4, StringValue: "options", Color: "grey", Order: "high" }
    ];
```

I want to filter out the objects that are in `this.balanceCodes` (based on ID)

So the desired result would be:

```
    this.result = [
        { ID: 3, StringValue: "extra", Color: "black", Order: "low" },
        { ID: 4, StringValue: "options", Color: "grey", Order: "high" }
    ];
```

how can I achieve this? I know I can easily filter out an object, but how can I do this for an entire array of objects?

I'm allowed to use Lodash.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`_.differenceBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#differenceBy) to find items in the 1st array (`allCodes`) that are not found in the 2nd array (`balanceCodes`):

```js
var balanceCodes = [
    { ID: 1, StringValue: "dummy" },
    { ID: 2, StringValue: "data" }
];
var allCodes = [
    { ID: 1, StringValue: "dummy", Color: "red", Order: "low" },
    { ID: 2, StringValue: "data", Color: "green", Order: "medium" },
    { ID: 3, StringValue: "extra", Color: "black", Order: "low" },
    { ID: 4, StringValue: "options", Color: "grey", Order: "high" }
];

var result = _.differenceBy(allCodes, balanceCodes, 'ID');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve this by using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), without having to use lodash:

```js
var balanceCodes = [
    { ID: 1, StringValue: "dummy" },
    { ID: 2, StringValue: "data" }
];

var allCodes = [
    { ID: 1, StringValue: "dummy", Color: "red", Order: "low" },
    { ID: 2, StringValue: "data", Color: "green", Order: "medium" },
    { ID: 3, StringValue: "extra", Color: "black", Order: "low" },
    { ID: 4, StringValue: "options", Color: "grey", Order: "high" }
];

var result = allCodes.filter((code) => 
  balanceCodes.every((balanceCode) => balanceCode.ID !== code.ID));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

_.remove would be your best bet. If the IDs are unique - something like this should suffice (using lodash):

```
for( let balanceCode of balanceCodes){
    _.remove( allCodes, (code) => { code.ID === balanceCode.ID })
}
```